# How to groupby and apply a function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
    period  remaining_et_months  property_id  beds
0        0                    0          329     1
1        1                    0          329     1
2        2                    1          329     1
3        3                    2          329     1
4        3                    2          329     1
5        4                    3          329     1
6        4                    3          329     1
7        4                    3          329     1
8        5                    4          329     1
9        5                    4          329     1
10       5                    4          329     1
11       5                    4          329     1
```

and I need to group this dataframe and apply a function so that I am able to compute a column called `dist_period`:

```
g = df.groupby(['property_id', 'beds', 'period'])
g.apply(some_function)
```

I need to group by `property_id`, `beds`, and `period`, because the dataframe is larger than the one in this example.

I don't have a clear idea how to achieve this, but what I want the column `dist_period` to be like this:

```
    period  remaining_et_months  dist_period
0        0                    0            0
1        1                    0            1 
2        2                    1            1
3        3                    2            1
4        3                    2            2
5        4                    3            1
6        4                    3            2
7        4                    3            3
8        5                    4            1
9        5                    4            2
10       5                    4            3
11       5                    4            4
```

Notice that when the group has just one element the value of `dist_period` is `period - remaining_et_months`, but when the group has more than one element (see when period is 3, 4 or 5), then a count starting at one is perform.

Comment: You need to reduce the problem to an equivalent one that represents the data you have and demonstrates what you want to do.  As your question is, I have no idea how you get from your first table to your second table.

Comment: @piRSquared, I have clear what I want to get, but I have no idea how to get it. Look when you group by, every group will have some numbers of elements. Taking the table from the example, there will be 6 groups. There are 3 groups which number of elements is 1, so the value for `dist_period` for those rows is `period - remaining_et_months`. The other three groups have more than one element, so for `period` equal to 3, I want that each element gets numerated starting at 1. Does it make sense?

Comment: Are remaining_et_months always period-1?

Comment: @user3212593, not only when the group has 1 element. Otherwise, the group gets counted. See when `period` is 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the cumcount for the counting on multiple row groups (edit: note that this starts counting from 0):

```
df['dist_period'] = df.groupby(['property_id', 'beds', 'period']).cumcount()
```

Then you just add the difference between period and remaining_et_months:

```
df['dist_period'] = df['period'] - df['remaining_et_months'] + df['dist_period']
```

Comment: this is a really good catch, and wow! you have solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: what if at some point the difference between `period` and `remaining_et_months` is greater than 1?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since you take df['period'] - df['remaining_et_months']. The difference will always be accounted for in this.

Comment: thank you so much once again. Your answer solves completely my problem.

Comment: No problem. Good to hear.